# Apache directory studio 'Open connection' has encountered an error

Tags: apache, ldap

I'm trying to set up Apache directory studio in my mac, but however when i try to create a connection i get this error "Apache directory studio 'Open connection' has encountered a problem".
[image]
I'm following this tutorial, http://directory.apache.org/studio/users-guide/ldap_browser/gettingstarted_create_connection.html. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A connection being refused will likely mean that either the address and port you are connecting to is being blocked or filtered for whatever reason, or nothing is running on the specified address and port.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the error,
*ldap: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed*

The cause for this issue is, I had changed the port from 10389 to 10390. Hence, it is trying to connect to old port.

When I changed the 'Connections' port to update value (Ex: 10390) and start the server, the issue resolved.

[image]